# Set colors in Matplotlib.pie by label name

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have created a large matrix of pie plots using a function that runs through a datafrane. I am only plotting in the pie charts two variables. When one of the variables is not present in the specific data, matplotlib automatically switches the colors. See sample picture below.

How would I make sure the colors stay consistent based on values? Would I manipulate the colors argument in my function?

my def code that I run the data through

```
#function to make matrix
def pie(v, l, color=None):
    plt.pie(v, labels=l.values, colors = ????, autopct='%0.f')

#function being called for data - l='coverage' 
g = sns.FacetGrid(market_covered_sum, col="mkt_mcap_decile", row="market", 
                  margin_titles=True)
g.map(pie, "MKT_Cap_mn", "coverage").set_axis_labels(" ", " ")
```

I want to keep the colors consistent, and change them to a color code once I can keep consistent.
[image]

Comment: I assume it would be something along the lines of `colors = [("orange" if data in l["covered"] else "blue") for data in l]`.

Comment: did not work. The column name in teh df is 'coverage' if that helps. Code to show the function in use and how 'coverage' is called upon.

Comment: Could you add example data and executable code?

Comment: I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359989/10306817