# Keep same color for each label in different pie charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having trouble keeping the same color for every label from one pie chart to another. As you can see in the image below, Matplotlib inverts the colors in the 2nd pie chart.I would like to keep red for the 'Frogs' label and green for the 'Hogs' label. 
I also tried to add the `label` parameter but then it just gives the wrong count. I also tried to reverse the colors in the 2nd chart with `colors=colors[::-1]`it works but is not sustainable because sometimes I have more than two labels.

[image]

Here's the code:

```py
sizes1 = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Frogs', 'Frogs']
sizes2 = ['Hogs', 'Hogs', 'Hogs', 'Frogs', 'Frogs']

colors=['red', 'green']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=sizes1, columns=['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=sizes2, columns=['a'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18,5))


df1['a'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',ax=ax[0],shadow=True, colors=colors)
df2['a'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',ax=ax[1],shadow=True, colors=colors)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a color dictionary and then use this mapping to assign the `colors` while plotting. This will keep the color scheme consistent across all the subplots.

```
colors={'Frogs':'red', 
        'Hogs':'green'}

df1['a'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',ax=ax[0],shadow=True, 
                                 colors=[colors[v] for v in df1['a'].value_counts().keys()])
df2['a'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',ax=ax[1],shadow=True, 
                                 colors=[colors[v] for v in df2['a'].value_counts().keys()])
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but is unfortunate in that you need to hard-code your values in your code, or else I guess have a function which generates your color dictionary.

Comment: To improve avoid hard coding you can use the matpotlib.colomaps library as follows

`from matplotlib import colormaps`

and then define as 

`colors = { label: color  for label, color in zip(['Frogs', 'Hogs'], colormaps['Dark2'].colors)}`

and then use the *colors* map as above